React Jest Test error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions
While executing the test cases, the test case is failing with error:
FAIL  src/tests/auth/SignIn.test.js (6.321 s)
● SignIn Component › dispatches signIn action on form submission

Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

  31 |   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  32 |     e.preventDefault();
> 33 |     dispatch(signIn(creds.email, creds.password));
        |     ^
  34 |     setCreds({ email: "", password: "" });
  35 |   };
  36 |

My testing structure looks like this:
In SignIn.jsx, the error is coming at:
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     dispatch(signIn(creds.email, creds.password));
     setCreds({ email: "", password: "" });
};

The signIn() method code is as follows:
export const signIn = (email, password) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .post(`${url}/signin`, { email, password })
      .then((token) => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", token.data);

        dispatch({
          type: "SIGN_IN",
          token: token.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);

        toast.error(error.response?.data, {
          position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        });
      });
  };
};

Can anybody guide how to solve this?
I have tried solving via other stackoverflow threads, but not helped. How to solve this via jest, i need help on that
